# Passing param to custom middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have some middleware that checks if user is logged in:

```
//mw.js
module.exports = {  
  auth: function(req, res, next) {
    //check if user is logged in here
  }
}
```

and I have a separate routes file that accepts a `client` used to make calls to a 3rd party service:

```
//routes.js
module.exports = function(app,client) {
  router.get('/', mw.auth, function (req, res) {

  });
}
```

As you can see, the route makes use of the middleware but how can I pass the `client` to the middleware so that it can make use of the 3rd party service too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way to pass arguments/configuration options to a middleware is by returning a function from the middleware that captures the arguments using a closure.

```
 //mw.js
 module.exports = {
      auth: function (client) {
        return function (req, res, next) {
          //use client
        };
      }
    }
```

...

```
//routes.js
module.exports = function(app,client) {
  router.get('/', mw.auth(client), function (req, res) {

  });
}
```

The [static file server middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static), for e.g., takes the base directory as an argument.

The following is an excerpt from my implementation of [json-rpc](https://github.com/cPu1/jsonFrame/blob/master/lib/jsonrpc.js). It captures the methods object and invokes methods on it as requests arrive.

```
var JsonRpcServer = require('./rpc-server');

module.exports = function jsonrpc (methods) {
    var jsonRpcServer = new JsonRpcServer(methods);
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var rpcResponse,
        rpcRequest = req.body,
        contentType = req.headers['content-type'];

        if(req.method === 'POST' && ~contentType.indexOf('application/json')) {
            rpcResponse = jsonRpcServer._handleRpc(rpcRequest);
            if(Array.isArray(rpcResponse) && rpcResponse.length || rpcResponse.id) {
                rpcResponse = JSON.stringify(rpcResponse);
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Length': String(Buffer.byteLength(rpcResponse)),
                    'Content-Type': contentType
                });
                res.end(rpcResponse);
            }
            else {
                res.end();
            }
        }
        else next();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach it to `app`:

```
//routes.js
module.exports = function(app,client) {
  app.client = client;
  router.get('/', mw.auth, function (req, res) {

  });
}

//mw.js
module.exports = {  
  auth: function(req, res, next) {
    //check if user is logged in here
    // use `req.app.client` here
  }
}
```